# Calculate $\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}^-} (1-\cos x)^{\tan x}$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I tried putting $\cos x = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2 x}}$, but I am not able to calculate the limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use substitution $t=\frac{\pi}{2}-x$ instead, it leads to $$\lim_{t\to 0^+}(1-\sin t)^{\cot t}$$ Now $\cot t=\frac{\cos t}{\sin t}$ and you can use the fact that $(1+f(t))^{\frac{1}{f(t)}}$ tends to $e$ as $f(t)$ tends to 0.

Comment: You want $t\to 0^+$, so I think you need $t=\frac{\pi}{2}-x.$

Comment: you're right, thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

1) Set $x=\dfrac\pi2-t$ $\;(t\to 0^-)$.

2) $\ln(1-u)\sim_0 -u$.

Answer (score 0):

Limits like these are often better dealt with by taking logarithms (and then exponentiate the found limit):
$$
\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}^-}\log\bigl((1-\cos x)^{\tan x}\bigr)=
\lim_{t\to0^+}-\cot t\log(1+\sin t)
$$
where the substitution $t=x-\frac{\pi}{2}$ has been performed.

Now the limit is
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}(-\cos t)\frac{\log(1+\sin t)}{\sin t}
$$
and the second factor can be computed with $t=\arcsin u$:
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\log(1+\sin t)}{\sin t}
=
\lim_{u\to0^+}\frac{\log(1+u)}{u}
$$

(Note: log is the natural logarithm.)